# Force refresh of modified JS & CSS file in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I've only read about two options for cakephp caching files:

- Rather you cache them all
- Or you don't cache any.

I want something in between. Something equivalent as what we've all been doing in any other site, using a version parameter:

script.js?v=2

This way we can manually or even automatically force the load of modified files and at the same time have it cached when no change is made on them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CakePHP provides a way of applying timestamps to assets like CSS and JS files that only refreshes when the file changes. This is an equivalent of doing 'script.js?v=2', Cake would generate URLs like 'script.js?1442387965'.

In CakePHP 3.x (in config/app.php):-

```
'Asset' => [
    'force'
]
```

In CakePHP 2.x (in app/Config/core.php):-

```
 Configure::write('Asset.timestamp', 'force');
```

If you only want to apply the timestamps whilst debug mode is enabled set the above to `true` instead of `force`.

Comment: There's a cost to doing that, as CakePHP [checks the filemtime for each asset to generate that timestamp](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/src/View/Helper/UrlHelper.php#L104-L139). Probably a better idea given the question to override that method to use `Configure::read('Site.version')` or similar. Note that [using query args may affect intermediary caches](http://serverfault.com/questions/401201/squid-cannot-cache-static-files-with-query-string).

Comment: @AD7six agreed there is a cost, in practice we've found this to be negligible. There is also no risk of an update to a production site being rolled out with amended assets that do not require the browser to refresh the cache. The comment in Cake next to this setting should perhaps highlight the performance cost for clarity.

Comment: Why is this an accepted answer? there is a difference between using timestamp and versioning. 'script.js?v=2' would cache your js or css while force timestamp would not.

Comment: We don't want to reload the assets each and every time page is opened. There must be some way to reload them only when we make some changes and update the site's version.

Comment: @MainPalYadav this method will only make the browser fetch a fresh copy of the asset if it has been modified as the timestamp is generated based on when the asset was last modified. Check the CakePHP code if you are unsure

Comment: @drmonkeyninja Thanks a lot. Just got a clear understanding.

Comment: As of CakePHP 3.7.7, at least, the listed code does not produce the desired result.  The following configuration _does_ produce the forced timestamp, added to the 'Asset' key in 

app.php: 'Asset' => [
        'timestamp' => 'force'
    ]

Comment: I am using CakePHP 3.5.2, I have tried setting  'Asset' => [
        'timestamp' => 'force',        
    ] as well 'Asset' => [ 'force' ]. but none seems to be working. it is not appending any kind of date timestamp in js or css file. I have used <?php echo $this->Html->script('login.js'); ?>. What am i doing wrong ?